# why this XPATH query is not working?

Tags: xpath

My XML document looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/fPhSRKrV)

When I run XPATH query `//collected_objects`, I don't get any nodeset selected. What am I doing wrong? I want to select the whole collected_objects node.

Comment: @marc_s, it seems like that should go into an answer, so this question can be marked as answered …

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your XML document has a **XML namespace** defined (`<oval_system_characteristics xmlns="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5"`) - you need to include that in your query!

How you can do this depends on what system/programming language you're using. In .NET / C#, you could do this something like this:

```
// create XmlDocument and load XML file
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(yourXmlFileNameHere);

// define XML namespace manager and a prefix for the XML namespace used
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5");

// get list of nodes, based on XPath - using the XML namespace manager
XmlNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes("//ns:collected_objects", mgr);
```